# Chess movements in 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, chess

I have a method public static char myMethod(char[][] board) in this method, I am trying to get it to insert a char array board 8x8 and the blank spaces are '-' marks. My approach to this is to go through the board and look for the piece like 'p' for black pawn and check the places it can move. If there is a 'K' white king there, then the method returns 'p' to tell me that the white king is in check by black pawn. for the knight method below, I tried all 8 combinations of how it moves but it does not work. And

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 'N') { // where can i fix the boundaries?

                // a = i;
                // b = j;

                whiteKnight = board[i + 1][j + 2];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
```

i even tried it this way for the boundaries but no difference

```
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    char whiteKnight = ' ';

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 'N') { // where can i fix the boundaries?

                a = i;
                b = j;
            if ((a + 1) < 7 && (b + 2) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a + 1][b + 2];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a + 1) < 7 && (b - 2) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a + 1][b - 2];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a - 1) < 7 && (b + 2) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a - 1][b + 2];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a - 1) < 7 && (b - 2) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a - 1][b - 2];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a + 2) < 7 && (b + 1) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a + 2][b + 1];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a + 2) < 7 && (b - 1) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a + 2][b - 1];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a - 2) < 7 && (b + 1) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a - 2][b + 1];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a - 2) < 7 && (b - 1) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a - 2][b - 1];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what your question is

Comment: @austinwernli i'm just wondering if anyone sees something wrong with this that i do not cuz it makes perfect sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Well of course i see something wrong with your code... To start with i notice `(a-1) < 7` when i guarantee you meant `(a-1) >= 0` Be wary of the copy/paste lol

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
char whiteKnight = ' ';

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == 'N') { // where can i fix the boundaries?

            a = i;
            b = j;
            if ((a + 1) < 7 && (b + 2) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a + 1][b + 2];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a + 1) < 7 && (b - 2) >= 0) {
                whiteKnight = board[a + 1][b - 2];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a - 1) >= 0 && (b + 2) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a - 1][b + 2];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a - 1) >= 0 && (b - 2) >= 0) {
                whiteKnight = board[a - 1][b - 2];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a + 2) < 7 && (b + 1) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a + 2][b + 1];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a + 2) < 7 && (b - 1) >= 0) {
                whiteKnight = board[a + 2][b - 1];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a - 2) >= 0 && (b + 1) < 7) {
                whiteKnight = board[a - 2][b + 1];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
            if ((a - 2) >= 0 && (b - 1) >= 0) {
                whiteKnight = board[a - 2][b - 1];
                if (whiteKnight == 'k') {
                    return 'N';
                }
            }
```

Comment: thats true thanks! I think there is something wrong with how its reading in the values because I don't see why it doesn't work. failing the test cases

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the many if statements, you could use this pattern (which is also possible for other chessmen):

```
void move(){
  for( int r = 0; r < 8; ++r ){
    for( int c = 0; c < 8; ++c ){
      if( b[r][c] == 'N' ){
        for( int y = Math.max( 0, r-2 ); y <= Math.min(7,r+2);++y ){
          for( int x = Math.max( 0, c-2 ); x <= Math.min(7,c+2);++x ){
            if( Math.abs(x-r)+Math.abs(x-c)==3 ){
              if( b[y][x] == 'k' ){
                b[y][x] = 'N';
                b[r][c] = ' ';
                return;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another approach would be to store

```
{-2,-1}, {-1,-2}, {1,-2}, {2,-1}, {2,1}, {1,2}, {-1,2}, {-2,1}
```

in an array jump[8][2] and iterated over these "jump distances", checking the board boundaries. This would also avoid the many ifs...

Comment: Lol them closing brackets though!

Comment: @austinwernli  One doesn't really iterate the board to find White's or Black's chessmen; it should be a single iteration over W's or B's remaining men. And the second option would reduce the inner loops to a single loop. - In any case: considerably less copy-paste-pitfalls which you have rightly pointed out.

Comment: @laune is this method outside of the other method? or what?

Comment: @user3511198 I don't have a clue as to the overall organization of your class(es). `move` is a method, that, given a class field char[][]b containing the letters you are using would find an element containing 'N' and move it to a position "in reach" containing 'k'. I have no idea how you accomodate the second block of code in your post.